# Mod Rewrite Regex - Multiple Negative Lookaheads

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, regex-lookarounds

I currently have the working Mod Rewrite Regex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?((?:cmd)[^/]*)/((?!(?:cmd)[.+]*)(.+)) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]
```

That regex takes the following URL and transforms it into the URL immediately below:

`www.site.com/cmd1/param/cmd2/param2/stillparam2` and turn it into `www.site.com/index.php?cmd1=param&cmd2=param2/stillparam2`

That works fine, but I would also like to create another negative lookahead assertion to ensure that a URL block - ie a `/texthere/` param - doesn't include an underscore.  An invalid string might look like: `www.test.com/cmd/thing/getparam_valuehere`; the regex should parse the `cmd/thing` as a key and value pair and ignore the rest of the string.  I would then also write another RewriteRule to have the block of the URL with the underscore in it added as another URL parameter.  The following URL translation would occur:

```
www.test.com/cmd/param1/cmd2/directory/param2/sortorder_5
www.test.com?cmd=param1&cmd2=directory/param2&sortorder=5
```

Please let me know if I have not been clear enough.  Any help would be great.

NB: I have tried using a negative lookahead nested inside the one already present - `(?!(?!))` - and have tried using an `|` on two negative lookaheads, but neither solutions worked.  I thought that perhaps something else was more fundamentally wrong?

Thanks all.

**Edit:** I have also tried the following - which I really thought would work (but obviously, didn't!)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?((?:cmd)[^/]*)/((?!(?:cmd)[.+]*)(?![.+]*(?:_)[.+]*)(.+)) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]
```

That does the following:

`www.test.com/cmd/param1/sortorder_1/` translates to
`www.test.com?cmd=param1/sortorder_1/`

When it should instead become: `www.test.com?cmd=param1&sortorder=2/`.  The rule to translate `/sortorder_2/` into`&sortorder=2` has not yet been created, but you can hopefully see what I mean).

Comment: _Lookbehinds_ must be of constant length, variable-length lookaheads should be OK.

Comment: Yes, definitely only negative lookaheads are being used here.  Thanks for the replied!

Comment: I have also tried the following:

`RewriteRule ^(.*/)?((?:cmd)[^/]*)/((?!(?:[A-Za-z0-9])*_+(?:[A-Za-z0-9])*)(.+)) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]`.  Here, I have removed the original (working) negative lookahead and replaced it with another one that should ensure an underscore is not present in a URL block before including it as part of a parameter.  This did not work, and generated the following query string:

`cmd=key/to/command/value_here/sortorder_5/`

It was my intention for it to stop at `/value_here/` so that I could validate the negative lookahead finds the underscore segment correctly.  No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about four days of experimenting, I ended up with a somewhat different solution than I had originally expected to find.  I simply removed all the actual URL manipulation to my index.php file and routed all requests through there.  Here is my (much cleaner) .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and here is the block of code I used to parse the entered URL:

preg_match_all('|/([A-Za-z0-9]+)*((?!/)[A-Za-z0-9-*.]*)|', $_GET['path'], $matches);

```
        // Remove all '$_GET' parameters from the actual $_GET superglobal:
        foreach($matches[0] as $k => $v) {
            $search = '/' . substr($v, 1);
            $_GET['path'] = str_replace($search, '', $_GET['path'], $count);
        }

        // Add $_GET params to URL args
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
            self::$get_arguments[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
        }

        // Retrieve all 'cmd' properties from the URL and create an array with them:
        preg_match_all('~(cmd[0-9]*)/(.+?)(?=(?:cmd)|(?:\z))~', $_GET['path'], $matches);

        if (isset($matches[1][0])) {
            return self::$url_arguments = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

On a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/frame_with_cms/frame/www/cmd/one/cmd2/two/cmd3/three/cmd4/four/getparam_valuepart1_valuepart2/cmd5/five/
```

It successfully produces these separate arrays which I then use to handle requests:

```
Array
(
    [getparam] => valuepart1_valuepart2
)
Array
(
    [cmd] => one/
    [cmd2] => two/
    [cmd3] => three/
    [cmd4] => four/
    [cmd5] => five/
)
```

Thanks to all who took the time to read and reply.

Comment: I have to admit my first thought was, why do this in an .htaccess file. However, this reply is not really a solution to you question, given the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to keep your working rule and rewrite the param_value to the query string before your current rule?

Something like

`RewriteRule ^(.*)?/([^_/]+)_([^/]+)/ $1/?$2=$3 [N,QSA]`

should append all /param_value/ parts in into the querystring as param=value.

Take care using the N flag, you might end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: I'll try that after work and post the outcome.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @CharStringI included the above rewrite rule before the first, and I got an infinte loop!  Thanks for the reply all the same, much appreciated.